# Change the color of a div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to coding so I am doing some practice exercises in which I need to use javascript to alter the image of a box in an html file. Everything seems to be working except for the "blue" button, even though I have used the same syntax as in all the other scripts. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function() {

    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px"

});

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function() {

    document.getElementById("box").style.color = "blue"

});

document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function() {

    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 0.5

});

document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function() {

    document.getElementById("box").style.height = "150px"

    document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = 1

    document.getElementById("box").style.color = "orange"

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript Intro</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>

    <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button id="button1">Grow</button>
    <button id="button2">Blue</button>
    <button id="button3">Fade</button>
    <button id="button4">Reset</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hint: color (i.e. foreground color) and background color are not the same thing

Comment: just change `.color` to `.backgroundColor` as you are trying to change the background color of the div

Comment: You say "font color" in your question title; that usually refers to the color of the text within the affected element. Your "box" div does not contain any text, so changing the font color doesn't do much. Please clarify, or people will guess, as they are now.

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
document.getElementById("box").style.color = "blue";
```

To this:

```
document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

And it should be fine. Make sure you do the same for your reset button.

The reason this works is because `color` and `backgroundColor` change 2 different things. `color` changes text color, and `backgroundColor` changes the element's background color.

Hope that helps.

Comment: an answer should always explain _why_

Comment: Fair enough - I added a brief description of the difference between color and backgroundColor.

Comment: The question title says "font color". I'm not sure how changing the `backgroundColor` changes the "font color".

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("box"));
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    document.getElementById("box").style.color = "red";

});
```

and

```
 <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px">Hello</div>
```

will show you text in red.

Comment: code-only answers are not useful. You should explain what the problem was and why your answer solves it.

Comment: document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function() {
 console.log(document.getElementById("box"));
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    document.getElementById("box").style.color = "red";

});
Backgron color will change the background while color will change teh color of all the items

Comment: don't tell me, tell the OP. Edit the answer. Code in comments is unreadable anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `.color` to `.backgroundColor` as others explained.

Also, it's good to mention that you could use jQuery like this: (I think jQuery's method is easier to read and work, especially if you want to change more than one attr at the time)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $("#box").css('height', '250px');
    });

    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $("#box").css('background-color', 'blue'); 
    });

    $("#button3").click(function(){
        $("#box").css('opacity', '0.5');
    });

    $("#button4").click(function(){
        $("#box").css('opacity', '1')
                 .css('background-color', 'orange')
                 .css('height', '150px');
    });

});
</script>
```